# Memory Warning while playing animated image view

Tags: ios, animation, uiimageview

I have the following code to play animation with images:

```
-(void)playPopAnimation:(void (^)(void))completion{

__block NSMutableArray *images;
float animationDuration = 1.0f;
images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:26];
    for(int i=1; i<26; i++){
        NSString *fileName = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bulut_pop%d",i] ofType:@"png"];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileName];
        //UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bulut_pop%d.png",i]];
        [images addObject:image];
    }
[Helper playSound:@"button_pop"];    
UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.itemImage.frame];
imageView.animationImages = images;
imageView.animationDuration = animationDuration;
imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1; // 0 = nonStop repeat
[self addSubview:imageView];
[imageView startAnimating];

self.imageButton.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginIgnoringInteractionEvents];
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, animationDuration * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_current_queue(), ^{
    //[self.delegate myItemCell:self cellDidTappedFor:[self item]];
    self.imageButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    images = nil;
});
```

Each time I call this function, memory increases by 10 MB. What is the good way to play animated image views?

Comment: You code looks good. Maybe the problem with memory might not be in this code. If a memory warning is received, it doesn't mean that the source is the current executing code. I advice you to check your other resources, controllers, etc. in tools, find out which ones using the most of memory. Also you can try to decrease your image size. There are many online tools, or exporting to exact required resolution for web and devices in photoshop. Try any of these.

Answer (score 1):

Each time you call this method, you add a new image view (with its array of images) to your view. You should refactor your code so that the creation of the array and imageView are inside an if clause testing whether imageView is nil, so that part only runs the first time the method is called (and make imageView a property).

Comment: I don't think this will avoid memory warning.

Comment: @iRaviiVooda, why do you think this will not help?

Comment: Every time, he allocs memory, he will get the memory warning. However, deallocation is also on the way (for this memory). The memory is not piling up in his code, Allocation and deallocation are in process. This will just reduce the number of memory warnings to 1 (doesn't mean no more warning right?). Hope this explains well.

Comment: @iRaviiVooda, he is piling up UIImageViews. Every time the method is called, he adds one as a subview and never removes it, so that image view is not deallocated. This image view has a strong pointer to the array of images in its animationImages property, so that isn't deallocated either.

Comment: Ohh! YES! Sorry. I totally forgot the pointer from `UIImageView`. Yes this is correct. Thanks.